# How to create a unextractable executable for a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have tried a lot of Batch-to-EXE applications but none of them is secure. We can simply extract the source files using WinRAR and read the batch sccript.

So is there any way to securely convert the batch file to exe so that it is not extractable and therefore the source code is not readable?

Comment: Do a search for "obfuscate batch file"

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538056/obfuscate-batch-files-so-that-they-cant-be-read-ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to develop a custom solution for this.

The reason why you can't extract executables written in "C" or similar languages is because the C code is translated into machine code. You lose variable names, comments, and sometimes even the way the code was structured, since it's not always an exact one-to-one translation. Identifying what the code does is possible with some tools (IDA Pro, etc) but you won't ever get the "original" code back.

Although I'm not sure what Batch-to-EXE programs you are using, most likely they work like powershell-to-exe: the script itself is not translated. Instead, the script is encapsulated by a small program that runs the script. I could be wrong here, it could be actually translating the script (I'd need to know what program you were using). [Rob van der Woude](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/scriptcompilers.php) has a good page on various different script compilers, and some disclaimers on batch compilers. I don't know of any that convert batch code into machine language.

If the source code must be protected, the cheapest option may be to use a different language. This may be quicker than developing your own compiler.

Another quick option might be to simply obfuscate your script, but this does not make it unreadable, just hard to read.